# Jquery UI - Sortable between the Div not Within Div

Tags: jquery, html, css, jquery-ui

[image: REF Image]

I have 'N' number of start row  (red border)
I want sortable(number box 1, 2, 3 etc..) form start row(red border) to receive row(green border).

sortable should not work within start row (red border).
And sortable within the receive row (green border) must work.

Note: **Here i want to only disable/ cancel sortable function within the start row(red border).**
Below script code used.

```
    $('.draggable-row').sortable({
     connectWith:".sortable-row"

         });

     $('.sortable-row').sortable({
     connectWith:".sortable-row"

     });
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/ezhil/2tn0903g/2/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `beforeStop` event of **Sortable** ,

```
 beforeStop: function (event, ui) {
        //$(ui.placeholder).parent()[0] gives target sort element
        //If this is current element revert sort
        if ($(ui.placeholder).parent()[0] == this) {
            $(this).sortable('cancel');
        }
    }
```

#### See the [working Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/2tn0903g/6/)

I hope this will help you .

Comment: Thanks Runcorn. This is what i expect. Also i want to add Class to currently we doing sortable item (this item), this should work after sortable completed.

Comment: If i try sortable within start row(red border) am getting below "TypeError:" in firebug console. anybody can resolve it.  **TypeError: this.placeholder[0].parentNode is null
 

this.placeholder[0].parentNode.removeChild(this.placeholder[0]);**

Comment: Is the `JsFiddle` working for you? If yes, what is the jqeury version you are using?

Comment: No same error comes in JsFiddle also.  you can check with above  "working Fiddle"  jquery: v1.9.1 and  jQuery UI - v1.11.2 . version file used.

Comment: It seems using `cancel` on `beforeStop` is raising the issue, So i modified it a little bit to perform same thing on `stop`.

Comment: what is the option to write **callback function** for **currently sortable item(this item)**. that should work when the sorting is completed. **( after items moved to receive row - green border)**. thanks advance.

Comment: You can use `update` or `change` or `receive` callback on green sorting list.

Comment: Demo: [link]( http://jsfiddle.net/ezhil/xfr6d437/ )  'Overflow-x:hidden' css  property affect the jquery-ui sortable  scroll:true

Comment: This is quite some time ago now, but this is exactly what I am looking for in general, rows instead of sortable columns. But if you wanted to add a box and delete a box, how could you this?